# Signed android app crashes

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, android-app-signing

I'm tying to publish my app on the market. But after i sign my apk and install it i get a crash before it even loads an activity. I've located the following error in the logCat

```
03-24 14:57:03.080: E/AndroidRuntime(4310): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.golfboxdk/com.golfboxdk.LoginActivity}: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.golfboxdk.LoginActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.golfboxdk-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.golfboxdk-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I've checked my manifest and i really cant figure out whats wrong. My app runs smoothly when I'm using an unsigned apk.

This is the start of my manifest

```
package="com.golfboxdk"
android:versionCode="5"
android:versionName="1.7.2" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:name="com.golfboxdk.utils.GolfBoxApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:killAfterRestore="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.golfboxdk.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Things i already tried:
Enabling all files under ->Project->Properties->java Build path->Order and Expert, followed with a clean.
Check if ProGuard is activated (it's not)

Comment: I think that you should check proguard settings. It doesnt run on debug build but runs on release.

Comment: Yes, unless you built this from stale source it looks like proguard probably trashed your Activity name, *or the name of something it depends on*.  I believe proguard provides a report file detailing what it did, or you can also consider running your signed apk through a decompiler to see what actually happened.  In the case of a broken dependency, there may be messages generated in logcat during app install/dexopting which might provide a clue.

Comment: Hi,

This happens to me too a lot, I use Eclipse to export the app, and every time I export it, the first thing I do is to check if it runs!

When I get such exception, which happens one time every 3 exports, I just re-export the app once or  twice until it runs correctly.

I frnakly don't know why it happens and I didn't try to dig g to understand. I always thought it was because of the size of the app (the apk is about 6Mo).

I hope this helps and also I'm interested in getting this clear too.

Comment: I've re exported it 8 times now, still not working. So i don't think its gonna solve itself:)

Comment: how do i check the proguard settings?(never heard of proguard before)

Comment: Proguard is not enabled, i get this commented in my project.properties  #proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

Comment: Manually remove the gen & bin folder, then do a clean and build and try again.

Comment: Tired that, didn't work. I've checked the answer that helped me. But thats for all of your suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Project > Uncheck build automatically
2. Clean the workspace
3. Manually build your project
4. Sign your apk and send it to device via bluetooth/wifi/email, etc.
5. Test it and release it if it works

Comment: Eclipse tries to auto build while your application is getting signed so it breaks your apk ;)

Comment: Dam you Eclipse...... :) saved my day man. Here i thought i needed to take some overtime.

Comment: Saved my day, buddy (:

Comment: My pleasure ;) so happy I helped

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue before with Eclipse/ADT. Sometimes it just doesn't seem to package up the APK correctly.

Typically a clean and build followed by exporting the signed APK again fixes it for me.

Answer (score 0):

No one said that there would be a problem with proguard, but only [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/f97kV6zD9X4)  solved my issue.